# Canonical nuke virus from orbit question?

Tags: discussion

I've been working on a blog post about dealing with virus infections for small businesses (most of my clients).

It occurred to me that I should look at serverfault to see if I missed any details for a set of 'nuke it from orbit + improve your rebuild process' instructions. There isn't anything out there that quite fits the bill.

Would it be advantageous to have a question of this nature listed for closing these questions as duplicates?

Don't want to put together another canonical answer that gets the amount of open and close votes my last one raised.

Comment: Doesn't this kind of fit the bill http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server ?

Answer (score 5):

We may already have a suitable Q&A. Most Security breach questions get closed as a duplicate of [How Do I deal With A Compromised Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server). If this doesn't fit the bill then there may already be one [here](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=nuke)

Comment: I would consider a workstation infected by a virus to be equivalent to a compromised server. That said, I'm not opposed to re-titling the question again ("How do I deal with a compromised system?") if it might not be obvious enough...

Answer (score 2):

What about this question? It's discussing worm infections on a LAN rather than viruses but it's all malware at the end of the day. I've tried to edit my answer to the question to make a bit more broad in scope.

[How do I deal with the removal/eradication of an unknown worm on our network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/339552/how-do-i-deal-with-the-removal-eradication-of-an-unknown-worm-on-our-network)

If you're talking about individual machines in an individual context, as you mention *small* business, then SU may have some stuff that's more orientated towards that scale of things. A lot of our assumptions on SF about 'nuke from orbit' implicitly include the idea that the business will have some tools and procedures to make rebuiling a system 'low cost' compared to the time and effort taken to clean an infected machine and that might not be true for a small business.